# How should I maintain Intel microcode?

Tags: 16.04, intel

I have installed *ubuntu-drivers-common* on my minimal Install of Ubuntu 16.04.
Should I run "*ubuntu-drivers autoinstall*" after any kernel update?
How should I maintain this package?

Comment: I feel like `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` are probably enough.

Answer (score 2):

The intel-microcode package (which contains the microcode update data) will refresh the initramfs by itself when it is updated.  You don't have to do anything.

You will get the new microcode automatically the next time you reboot, as the microcode updated is (nowadays) only applied during boot, for several technical reasons.